# Titanium.Ti.Media.VideoPlayer.movieControlMode DEPRECATED

Tags: javascript, iphone, video, titanium, deprecated

I have and app which appears to play a local video clip just fine but when I run it in the iPhone simulator it says [WARN] Titanium.Ti.Media.VideoPlayer.movieControlMode DEPRECATED in 1.8.0, in favor of Ti.Media.VideoPlayer.mediaControlStyle: REMOVED in 1.9.0.

This is my code. How should it read? I can't get it to work simply swapping  them.

```
var options = {
url: 'ch4_3.m4v',
backgroundColor: '#111',
scalingMode: Titanium.Media.VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_FILL,
movieControlMode: Titanium.Media.VIDEO_CONTROL_DEFAULT 
};

var activeMovie = Titanium.Media.createVideoPlayer(options) 
    win.orientationModes = [Titanium.UI.LANDSCAPE_LEFT,Titanium.UI.LANDSCAPE_RIGHT];        
    Titanium.UI.orientation = Titanium.UI.LANDSCAPE_LEFT
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

the line should be

```
mediaControlStyle : Titanium.Media.VIDEO_CONTROL_DEFAULT,
```

works fine